# Is it possible to have 3G and Wifi connections at the same time? even using with NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-wifi, 3g

Is it possible to have 3G and Wifi connections at the same time?

Comment: Not that I would know. How'd that work anyway? There's no API for switching between different active network connections.

Comment: No that I'm know. I can know which state connection or force one of them, but I can't do both connecetion.
You can using for example with ConectivityManager and WifiManager

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can check active network interfaces programmatically. E.g. with [this](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/enumerating-network-interfaces-on-linux.html) code:

```
/*
  Example code to obtain IP and MAC for all available interfaces on Linux.
  by Adam Pierce <adam@doctort.org>

http://www.doctort.org/adam/

*/

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    char          buf[1024];
    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq *ifr;
    int           sck;
    int           nInterfaces;
    int           i;

/* Get a socket handle. */
    sck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sck < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

/* Query available interfaces. */
    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(buf);
    ifc.ifc_buf = buf;
    if(ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) < 0)
    {
        perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF)");
        return 1;
    }

/* Iterate through the list of interfaces. */
    ifr         = ifc.ifc_req;
    nInterfaces = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);
    for(i = 0; i < nInterfaces; i++)
    {
        struct ifreq *item = &ifr[i];

    /* Show the device name and IP address */
        printf("%s: IP %s",
               item->ifr_name,
               inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&item->ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

    /* Get the MAC address */
        if(ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFHWADDR, item) < 0)
        {
            perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR)");
            return 1;
        }

    /* Get the broadcast address (added by Eric) */
        if(ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFBRDADDR, item) >= 0)
            printf(", BROADCAST %s", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&item->ifr_broadaddr)->sin_addr));
        printf("\n");
    }

        return 0;
}
```

You can compile it for Android and then launch via ADB shell. On my device it gives next output:

```
shell@mako:/ $ /data/local/tmp/ifenum                                          
lo: IP 127.0.0.1, BROADCAST 0.0.0.0
rmnet_usb0: IP 100.105.60.161, BROADCAST 0.0.0.0
wlan0: IP 192.168.0.100, BROADCAST 192.168.0.255
```

As you can see, my device is connected to two different networks, and I can freely choose what to use. (`rmnet_usb0` is provided by my mobile carrier, and actually is an Edge network, but IMO 3G ends with the same result)

P.S. Most of applications don't care about interface that they use and bind their sockets to `INADDR_ANY`, obviously system will use the "best" of available networks.

Comment: Okay tnx a lot... When I get all the networks such as yours, can I send packet (transmission) for example in 3G and get receive in WIFI? Thank  you for any help... @Serhio

Comment: @Royal In general - no. Each created socket uses only one network interface both for transmitting and receiving. You can workaround it by creating of two connections and then bind them to different interfaces on your device. But in this case remote end should manually select proper connection from which it should read requests and to which it should write replies.